# android IllegalStateException, database already closed

Tags: android, sqlite, illegalstateexception

I am using SimpleCursorAdapter  and database table to populate a List. The list gets populated and I am able to click on list items to open the desired item(This starts a new activity). The problem is when I press the back key, I got Following error.

IllegalStateException: database already closed.

My code is as follows:

```
public class populatingLectures extends ListActivity{

private static String[] FROM = {SUBJECT, TOPIC, LECTURENUMBER, DATE };
private static int[] TO = {R.id.subject, R.id.topic,
        R.id.lecturenumber, R.id.date };
private static String[] data = { SUBJECT, TOPIC, LECTURENUMBER, _DATA };
private static String ORDER_BY = DATE + " DESC";
private SoftCopyDatabase lectures;  
String gotId;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    SoftCopyDatabase lectures = new SoftCopyDatabase(this);
    try {
        Cursor cursor = getLectures();
        showLectures(cursor);
    } finally {
        lectures.close();
    }
}

public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    lectures = new SoftCopyDatabase(this);
    try {
        Cursor cursor = getLectures();
        showLectures(cursor);
    } finally {
        lectures.close();
    }
}

private Cursor getLectures() {

    SQLiteDatabase db = lectures.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME,null, "subject=?", new String[] {OpenClick.subjectName}, null, null,
            ORDER_BY);
    startManagingCursor(cursor);
    return cursor;
}


private void showLectures(Cursor cursor) {

    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            R.layout.item_lectures, cursor, FROM, TO);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}

private Cursor getFileName(String ID) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = lectures.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, data, "_ID=?",
            new String[] { ID }, null, null, null);
    startManagingCursor(cursor);
    return cursor;
}


@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView listView, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(listView, view, position, id);

             //...CODE TO START NEW ACTIVITY

    }
}


}
```

Kindly tell me what mistake am I doing. Because I am not closing the database explicitly any where.

Regards,
Waneya Iqbal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
finally
{       
 lectures.close();
}
```

I think this line gives the exception, so put it in `onDestroy()`.

Comment: you can upvote or mark as the correct answer if you find it right. It is useful for other user. thnx.

Answer (score 0):

You're closing the database as soon as you populate the list. You should move the

```
lectures.close()
```

line from onStart() to onDestroy(), which will make sure your database gets closed when the activity is complete, rather than as soon as the list is populated.